# Descargar Archivos en Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, archivo, xamarin

Estoy tratando de descargar archivos **pdf** mas que todo desde una aplicación Xamarin.

Teoricamente hay un `ListView` a la que al darle *Tapped* ira a la base de datos a buscar el URL, lo obtiene y lo descargará.

Lo que he encontrado en internet es que se puede hacer con `WebClient` pero no me funciona. Aquí hay un intento simple con descargar un **exe**, debería funcionar con cualquier archivo.

```
private void ListaView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
         client.DownloadFile("https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe", "vlc.exe");
        DisplayAlert("Archivo Descargado", "El archivo ha sido descargado", "OK");
}
```

Pero me da un error de este tipo:

> {System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient
>   request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/vlc.exe" is denied.

No se si tengo mal el concepto del segundo parámetro del `DownloadFile`, que según entiendo puede escribirse solo el nombre del archivo pero no se. Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: debes de agregar los permisos necesarios para poder guardar el archivo (INTERNET, WRITE EXTRENAL STORAGE) descargado en algun lado por ejemplo sdcard: webClient.DownloadFile("URL", "/sdcard/download/Test.xls");

Comment: Agregue las causas por las cuales se obtiene el error mostrado, en este caso el url que especificas me parece el principal problema ya que la url no descargara el archivo automáticamente, prueba por ejemplo con esta url : http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf y guarda un pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debes asegurar tener los permisos `INTERNET` y `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Ahora entonces, al usar el método `DownloadFile()` el segundo parámetro debe ser el nombre del archivo local que recibiría los datos:

```
client.DownloadFile("https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe",  "vlc.exe");
```

---

Con respecto a tu código se tiene:

```
DownloadFile (Uri address, string fileName);
```

> `address`: El URI especificado como una Cadena, desde la cual descargar
>   datos.
>
> `fileName`: El nombre del archivo local que recibirá los datos.

y **el error [WebException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8) se produce por las siguientes causas**:

> - El URI formado al combinar BaseAddress y la dirección no es válido.
> - nombre de archivo (`fileName`) es nulo o vacío.
> - El archivo no existe (`address`).
> - Se produjo un error al descargar los datos (Revisar permisos).

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. Según entiendo, entonces debe existir un archivo para que reciba los datos?. Por que los permisos si están habilitados.

Comment: Si pero en este caso el problema es el url : https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe , al cargar esta url no es propiamente de un archivo, si no que la url realiza la descarga del archivo, no lo hace automaticamente, ese debe ser el problema, trata de descargar un pdf , por ejemplo con esta url : https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf y guarda un pdf

Comment: acabo de tratar con ese link y el resultado es el mismo:

Comment: client.DownloadFile("africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "doc.pdf"); Pero me hace falta entonces crear el archivo que recibira los datos

Comment: Si, revisa que tengas los permisos comentados.

Comment: Lo lamento, pero sigo tratando y almenos ahora me pasa del Try y me lanza el DisplayAlert, y dice que lo guardo en /data/user/0/com.companyname.helena/files/archivo.pdf. Pero al ir a ese directorio no encuentro nada. en el administrador de archivos voy a /android/data/com.companyname.helena/files. Pero solo encuentro una carpeta llamada ._override_ y allí adentro solo hay dll y otros archivos así.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la siguiente referencia [How to download files in Xamarin](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-files-in-xamarin-forms/) 
Primero que nada asegurate de tener los permisos necesarios:

> **Android**
>
> En las propiedades del proyecto Android, agrega las siguientes opciones. 
>   `INTERNET` 
>   `WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE`
>
> ---
>
> **iOS**
>
> En las propiedades del proyecto iOS abre el archivo Info.plist con el editor de XML 
>   Y agrega los siguientes permisos.
>
> - Permisos para guardar un archivo: 
>     `<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription </key>`
>     `<string>Need permission to save files.</string>`
> - Permisos para acceder a los archivos: 
>     `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription </key>` 
>     `<string>Need permission to access files.</string>`
>     
>     **Desde iOS 11**, se siguen patrones de permisos separados para guardar acceder al almacenamiento o a la galería.

En el [siguiente caso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033619/an-exception-occurred-during-a-webclient-request-while-using-c-sharp-asp-net) especifica que el error radica en la ubicación del archivo, tiene que ser una ruta en el dispositivo, por lo que puedes utilizar la carpeta temporal. 
Por consiguiente puedes crear una ruta temporal donde se descargará el archivo y después guardarlo. 

**Nota:** 
*Este es un proceso que va a demorar tiempo así que recomiendo que hagas el evento asíncrono para que no se quede esperando a que termine el proceso de la descarga*.

```
 private async void ListaView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
    var temp_path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var file_name = "vlc.exe";
    temp_path = Path.Combine(temp_path, file_name);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += async (s,args) => 
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Archivo Descargado", "El archivo ha sido descargado", "OK");
        };
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe"), temp_path);
    await DisplayAlert("Información", "Se ha comenzado la descarga del archivo", "OK");
 }
```

---

Lo único malo es que no hay ninguna información del proceso de descarga, simplemente al final te mostraria la notificación.

Mi recomendación sería usar el navegador que viene por defecto en el dispositivo y desde ahí mandar la descarga del archivo.

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe"));
```

---

**Actualización [Android]**: [Cómo solicitar permisos de la app](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios pueden revocar
>   permisos desde cualquier app en cualquier momento, aunque la app esté
>   orientada a un nivel de API inferior

Esto significa que se debe solicitar que al usuario que apruebe cada solicitud durante el tiempo de ejecución (en Android 6.0 o versiones posteriores).

[image: Allow location permissions on android app (API >=23)]